# Lock wait timeout apache derby database

Tags: timeout, derby

I have a derby database to store user state to a table. My application updates the record of the user table very frequently resulting into lock wait timeout. And for each user logged in this update query is fired resulting into table locks.

Can i change the table to row-level locking instead of table locking.

Also, will indexing help to update the user rows?

How do i optimize my table to deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to start in understanding why lock wait timeouts occur: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/LockDebugging